# Draw multiple shapes on a canvas out of arrays of points

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a html page with a canvas which connects to a webserver and receives some array of points that need to be drawn on the canvas.

When the connection establishes, I get a shape as the main template. This will remain constant through the session. Then I get some other shapes.

My problem is I can not figure out how can I draw the main shape (the template) only once and then easily draw and clean the other shapes on the canvas. Here is my application flow:

1 - Draw the main template shape
2 - When a new shape arrives, draw it on the canvas (without clearing the already drawn template)
3- When a newer shape arrives, draw the older shape (NOT the template) and draw the new shape

I need to draw the first template only once because I get a big number of points and I do time consuming calculations on them. I do not want to redraw this template every time a new shape arrives...

Is the re a way to achieve this? It should also account for page resize, etc...

I have prepared the minimal example below to simulate what I need...

```js
// Main template shape
let template = [{x: 10, y:10}, {x: 120, y:10}, {x: 110, y:110}, {x: 50, y:175}];

// Some shapes
let shapes = [
    [{x: 20, y:20}, {x: 110, y:20}, {x: 100, y:100}, {x: 60, y:145}],
    [{x: 30, y:30}, {x: 100, y:30}, {x: 90, y:90}, {x: 70, y:135}],
    [{x: 40, y:40}, {x: 90, y:40}, {x: 80, y:70}, {x: 80, y:125}],
];

let shapeIndex = 0; // To cycle through shapes array

let canvas = {}; // Canvas to draw on
let ctx = {}; // Context of the Canvas

// Init elements
$( document ).ready(function() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
});

// Draw the template
function drawTemplate() {
    ctx.save();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'yellow';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    for(let point of template) {
        ctx.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
    }
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.restore();
}

// Draw one shape from the shapes array
function drawShape() {
    ctx.save();

    ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(127,127,127,0.5)';
    ctx.beginPath();

    let points = getShapeFromArray();
    for(point of points) {
        ctx.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
    }
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.restore();
}

// Draw one shape from the shapes array
function drawShape() {

    // How to clear the perviously drawn shape, if any?

    ctx.save();

    ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(127,127,127,0.5)';
    ctx.beginPath();

    let points = getShapeFromArray();
    for(point of points) {
        ctx.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
    }
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.restore();
}

// Helper to get next element in the array
function getShapeFromArray() {
    if(shapeIndex == shapes.length) {
        shapeIndex = 0;
    }
    return shapes[shapeIndex++];

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Hahaha!</title>
</head>

<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
<p style="text-align: left">
    <button onclick="drawTemplate()">draw template</button>
    <button onclick="drawShape()">draw shape</button>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: not a great solution, but if it's just a graphic representation, just position a new Canvas below this, and draw the template on the below canvas, so that you can use `clearRect` or whatever you need on the above one

Comment: Clear the canvas and redraw only what is visible each time there is a change

Comment: @Blindman67 Clearing will return a white (default background color) canvas. Maybe I didnt understand what you mean? is there a special clear function?

Comment: There is no special clear function, From the cleared (transparent) canvas after calling  `ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height)` redraw all content that is visible

Comment: If redrawing is bothering so much you should consider using a library to do it for you: http://fabricjs.com/ sounds like a good candidate, that way you can show, hide, delete and add objects and shapes with fewer headaches ... and focus your time on what you really trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @DEKKER here is working solution

```js
canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Main template shape
let template = [{x: 10, y:10}, {x: 120, y:10}, {x: 110, y:110}, {x: 50, y:175}];

// Some shapes
let shapes = [];
// put template first into our bucket
shapes.push( template ) ;

// helper fn.
// random int with limits
let RI = function (min, max) {
  if (max == null) { max = min; min = 0; }
  if (min > max) { var tmp = min; min = max; max = tmp; }
  return Math.floor(min + (max - min + 1) * Math.random());
}
// returns array with 3 random points
function genPoint(){
  return [ {x: RI(1, 199), y: RI(1, 199)}, {x: RI(1, 199), y: RI(1, 199)}, {x: RI(1, 199), y: RI(1, 199)}, {x: RI(1, 199), y: RI(1, 199)} ];
}



// Draw the template
function drawPoly( points, isTemplate = false ) {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = (isTemplate) ? 'yellow' : 'white';
  ctx.fillStyle = (isTemplate) ? 'red' : 'rgba(127,127,127,0.5)';
  for( let point of points ) {
    ctx.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
  }
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();
}

// main logic
function drawPoint( ajaxData = false ){
  // if bucket contains more additional points (poly's)
  // draw last two poly's
  if( shapes.length > 2 ) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height ); // clear canvas
    drawPoly( shapes[ shapes.length -2 ], false ); // draw last two
    drawPoly( shapes[ shapes.length -1 ], false );
  } else {
    drawPoly( shapes[ shapes.length -1 ], ( shapes.length == 1 )  ) ;
  }
  // push random `genPoint` data in `shapes` array or ajaxData or whatsoever
  shapes.push( ( ajaxData ) ? ajaxData : genPoint() ); // add new point on stack
}

// draw and demo working system
setInterval( drawPoint, 2000 );
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

I'll comment what I've added into your code:

- main logic is in `function drawPoint( ajaxData = false ){..}` function. It takes new poly as parameter so you can automatically plug it into your program logic with ajax data I guess
- I've simplified your code a bit with only one function that makes drawing - it's `function drawPoly( points, isTemplate = false ){..}`
- two simple helper functions `RI` as random integer and `genPoint` as point generator
- removed `jQuery` as that dep is not needed

Comment: Thanks for going into the effort :)